# goto was not expected at this time batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

```
@echo off
:start
set string=
set lo=1
set a=0
set b=0
set cl=1
set cloop=
set google=0
set k=0
set r=0
set id=
set t=0
set f=0

set /p string=? 
if defined string (
echo %string%
goto loop
) else (
echo please enter a string
goto start
)
:loop
set a=
for /f "tokens=%lo%" %%G IN ("%string%") DO echo %%G 
if defined a (
echo %a%
set google=0
set /p cloop=<greetings.txt
pause
:cloop
set b=
for /f "tokens=%cl%" %%g IN ("%cloop%") DO set b=%%g
if defined string (
if %a%==%b% goto greetings
set /a cl=%cl%+1
goto cloop
) else (
set cl=0
set /a lo=%lo%+1
goto loop
)
) else (
goto google
)
:greetings
set f=0
set k=0
set r=0
set /p id=<greetingtone.dat
for /f "tokens=%cl%" %%g IN ("%id%") DO set t=%%g
start greeting.bat
call greeting.bat
goto talk
:google
echo not done yet
pause
goto start
```

i have narrowed it down to this line 
     if %a%==%b% goto greetings
when i remove it it runs
 i have looked but i have no idea why it does not work
**please help** the greetings.txt has "hi hello grunt"
i think it might be the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal reason for that an unexpected word in an `IF` statement is that `IF` has a very specific syntax, `IF item1 operator item2 actionstatement(s)`.

What is likely to be happening is that item1 **AND** item2 appear to be missing, so `IF` resolves that as `IF == goto greetings`. Since `goto` is not one of its known `operators` (`==`, `equ`, `neq`, `leq`, `lss`, `geq`, gtr`) then it complains.

The question from here is - why do `%a%` and `%b%` appear to be empty?

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered. In your case, that means the outermost `IF` - in `if defined string`.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Next problem is using a label within a block. Not a good idea. On some versions, a label will terminate the block. Call a subroutine instead.

```
 call :cloop

...
goto start
:cloop
 (whatever needs to be done)
goto :eof
```

(note that `:cloop` and `:EOF` have a **required** colon. on `cloop` it means "this is an internal subroutine - it's in the cuurrent batchfile." `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`.)

Answer (score 2):

If `%a%` or `%b%` are empty values, it is likely the compare is incomplete, and it is saying that the `goto` is not expected yet.  For instance, if you type the following at a `C:\` prompt:

```
c:\>if a== echo ok

c:\>if ==a echo ok
echo was unexpected at this time.

c:\>if == echo ok
ok was unexpected at this time.

c:\>
```

If you enclose each value in quotes, then the comparison will still work even if one or both of the values are empty.  For instance:

```
if "%a%"=="%b%" goto greetings
```

Comment: +1, You diagnosed the OP's specific question, but there are other issues with the code, such that simply adding quotes will not fix the code. See Magoo's answer.